# Nginx In Docker: location config not working

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

Attaching docker File.

```
FROM nginx:1.17.4-alpine

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
# expose port 4202
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The nginx config(default.conf) is shown below

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {     
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /site {
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;  
    }

}
```

I successfully built and executed docker container using `docker run -p 4202:80 imageprocessor:v1`

But whenever I try to browse localhost:4203/site, it is redirecting to localhost/site

Why is this happening? Please help.

Comment: Is there any other way to map with 4202?, even it is tough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx doesn't know you are mapping port 4202 to port 80.

When you provide the URI `/site`, Nginx will externally redirect to `/site/`. This latter URI is then processed according to the `index` directive.

You have two options:

### 1) avoid external redirections being generated by Nginx

```
location /site {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;  

    rewrite ^/site$ /site/ last;
}
```

This should generate an internal redirect for the URI `/site`. You may need to add a more general solution if you have other directories under this one. Also, relative URIs (if applicable) will not work correctly as the trailing `/` will be missing.

### 2) explicitly generate the redirection with the required port number

```
location /site {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;  

    location ~ [^/]$ {
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            return 302 http://$http_host$uri/$is_args$args;
        }
    }
}
```

If the requested URI points to a directory, construct an external redirect with all the required parameters, including a trailing `/`. The value of `$http_host` should include the port in the original request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) for all the Nginx variables.

Comment: Hi Thanks, the first method is producing 500 Internal Server Error. The second method I didnt quite understand. Could you please explaing $host, $uri etc are. Also the port number 4202 is dynamic, so it shouldn't be present in config file

Comment: There was an error in the first example that has been corrected and the second example has been updated to avoid explicitly specifying the original port.

Comment: Hi, first method is working fine. Thanks for the support. But in second method, when docker run, I am getting following error --->>> [emerg] 1#1: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1